# What does "un plat (du jour)" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I came about this sentence: "un plat (du jour)". When you literally translate it to English, it doesn't make much sense. Is it used for something particular in French?

Comment: It would have been much better/nicer if you had given the context where you saw the phrase, although in that case of course we can guess it's on a menu. The exact translation into English is *Today's special* (at least in Britain), but it needs explaining because I suppose each language has a colloquial phrase to say that and you might not have it in your native language.

Answer (score 3):

Un restaurant offre une *carte* sur laquelle il y a un ou plusieurs *menus*, et des *plats* à l'unité (entrée, plat, dessert).

Cette carte est valable sur une période plus ou moins longue ; souvent elle est renouvelée lorsque l'on change de saison, en fonction des fruits et légumes disponibles.

Le *plat du jour* est le plat préparé pour le *service* d'un seul jour ; c'est souvent une des spécialités du restaurant.

En général le plat du jour est renouvelé chaque jour de la semaine ; on voit souvent "Couscous - jeudi et vendredi" par exemple, ou : aujourd'hui "Petit salé aux lentilles" plat traditionnellement servi dans les bistrots, les brasseries.

Comment: Précisons que dans « entrée, plat, dessert », le mot *plat* désigne le *plat principal*.

Answer (score 0):

In culinary matters the noun *plat* can mean two things in French :

- [The dish](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plat_%28ustensile%29), usually made of earthenware, into which we put the food to display it on the table.
- In a meal, each item served as a course. Each one can include several items of food, for example, un *steak frites* is one course (*plat*) with two items.

It's this last meaning that *plat* has in *le plat du jour*.

Les restaurants proposent en général une carte où on peut choisir des plats séparément et parfois un ou plusieurs [menus](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_%28restauration%29) à différents prix. En France certains restaurants, et les brasseries très souvent, proposent pour le déjeuner, en plus de la carte un *plat du jour*, qui :

- est différent chaque jour (d'où son nom), mais bien sûr pas 365 jours par an ;  les habitués d'un restaurant retrouvent les mêmes plat du jour qui reviennent avec une certaine régularité,
- le plat du jour est souvent fonction des produits disponibles sur le marché et donc connaît des variations saisonnières,
- certains restaurants essaient de proposer des spécialités culinaires régionales dans ces plats du jour.

L'article (surtout historique) [plat du jour sur Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plat_du_jour#Plat_du_jour_sur_internet). À noter qu'il ne figure aucune traduction de cet article, coutume très française ?

Quelques illustrations à voir sur la toile: [1](http://www.auberge-domfessel.com/plat-du-jour/), [2](http://www.fourchette-et-sable-blanc.fr/Restaurant.html), [3](http://barlasardine.com/restaurant-place-sainte-marthe/notre-menu-et-nos-petits-plats/).

Comment: English has the same polysemy, *dish* can mean the plate or its content. And *dish of the day* is common in English, I think even more common than *special*.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192792/dish-of-the-day-vs-todays-special

Comment: @Laure: le changement de langage est volontaire ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez De langue ? Heu..  dans un certain sens. Mais s'il faut adapter (je ne fais pas de traductions) c'est envisageable...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Par contre le fait de ne pas avoir mis de noms de restaurants était tout à fait volontaire, je ne cherche pas à faire de pub à des restaurants que je ne connais pas, faire un lien est le maximum que j'ai eu du mal à dépasser, sachant que le PO prépare un examen, je pensais que ça lui serait utile de pouvoir travailler avec des images.

Comment: @Gilles "dish of the day" being the literal translation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_phrases_used_by_English_speakers#P) that OP did not understand since they are not anglophone  using the word dish which has the same polysemy in as in French does not really seem a good idea for an explanation. We are not answering their question if we do not clear the polysemy. In English at least there are two different words.

Comment: @Gilles I have found that "Today's special'(s)" is more common in British pubs than "Dish of the Day", and it seems it is [in the US as well](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/192792/12918).